# PHP effeciency vs HTML?

Tags: php, performance

I was wondering what seems to be more efficient. If I need to use

```
ThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimes
```

a lot in my code, is it more efficient, server wise, to actually set up something like

```
$repeat = 'ThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimes'
```

and then use

```
<?php echo $repeat; ?>
```

in it's place?

Comment: It is more "efficient" to write the code that is [more] maintainable.

Comment: With a caching server in between it does not matter. Otherwise, it still does not matter. Btw, when in doubt, benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP will take longer because it has to run the code and then output it as HTML (using echo.) HTML will just go down the page and display it as many times as it's used.

EDIT: It looks like you are specifically focusing on the server instead of speed to the user. Other answers are correct that it will be a smaller file size to use the PHP.

Comment: The speed difference is marginal, at best. And, supposing a [fringe] case where the line was repeated 1000+ times, the PHP may be faster than reading from the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

**Define efficient.**  PHP processing *slightly* takes longer than straight HTML, even when both are run through the PHP parser.  However, your code looks cleaner and is easier to manage, especially if you need to make changes to the line being repeated, the number of times it is repeated, or if it is repeated in disparate places.  And it takes less space on the server, so the code may actually be *slightly* faster because of the excess hard drive read times, depending on just how many times that line is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

pure html is the most efficient way to get this running. php needs to parsed by the server so it needs some additional process before it can be send to the user client. if you don't change your "$repeat" a lot of times you can use pure html. to be honest i dont think your "super long line of html" is so long that php or html takes a lot of time anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Execution time? Not sure.

For repeating the string? PHP. (Saves on server space).

```
<?php
$string = 'ThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimes';
for($i = 0; i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $string;
}

?>
```

Will use less space than "ThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimesThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimesThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimesThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimesThisIsMySuperLongLineOfHTMLCodeThatIsRepeatedManyTimes" etc ....

Comment: My thumb-drive has a 32GB capacity. Space is overrated.

Comment: Space isn't overrated in larger systems. If space isn't an issue for you, then HTML is better.